# Save image from scrollview to photo album

Tags: iphone, ios6

How to save image from scrollview to photalbum when i m using

```
 NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

in scrollview to display image view.

```
UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
   imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 61;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_imageScrollView._image, self, nil, nil);

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Getting message in red on statement

```
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_imageScrollView._image, self, nil, nil);
```

that `property _image not found on object of type uiscrollview.`

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hang on to the image with a separate pointer, or if the scroll view is the only pointer to it, you can find it with a tag:

```
// right after
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
// give it a tag
imageView.tag = 128;   // any int that is unique relative to other tags in the scroll view
```

// find it with the tag...

```
case 0:
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[imageScrollView viewWithTag:128];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, self, nil, nil);

    // notice, there's also no property called _image on an imageView
```

Comment: getting message on this one that expected expression  UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[_imageScrollView viewWithTag:128];

Comment: Is there a little cursor in the message pointing at _imageScrollView?  My guess is that your class doesn't hold an ivar of that name.  Please paste the code that declares imageScrollView.

Comment: if i just do [_imageScrollView viewWithTag:128];  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, self, nil, nil); meesages are gone but not saving image

Comment: Yeah - as a matter of fact, I see that you refer to it without the _underscore elsewhere in the code.  Try no underscores (I'll edit).

Comment: with this UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[imageScrollView viewWithTag:128]; it gives message expected expression

Comment: Ok.  Let's check whether a. you have a scroll view there, b. you get an imageview out, and c. whether it has an image in it:  NSLog@"scrollview = %@", imageScrollView);  NSLog(@"%@", imageView);  NSLog@"%@", imageView.image);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17755/discussion-between-danh-and-user1452248)